# SOAP Connection Reset

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, soapui

I successfully used the weimport maven tool generated the Jar file against the client WSD, which is backed by a .net SOAP service

when I making a request from my java client code, I am getting the following log

```
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: multipart/related;start="<rootpart*dbea05e3-9997-4835-965c-02b1ed77e6b6@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:dbea05e3-9997-4835-965c-02b1ed77e6b6";start-info="text/xml"
SOAPAction: "http://xxx/2013/xxx/RemotexxxService/UpdateProfile"
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.10 svn-revision#919b322c92f13ad085a933e8dd6dd35d4947364b
--uuid:dbea05e3-9997-4835-965c-02b1ed77e6b6
Content-Id: <rootpart*dbea05e3-9997-4835-965c-02b1ed77e6b6@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

and I am getting the following error

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
```

however when I copy past the entire SOAP message and try it in the SOAPUI, it does work..

I have noticed the SOAP UI has different http header generated

```
POST http://coreservices-uat.legendonlineservices.co.uk/IRemoteContactUpdateService.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://Infrastructure/2013/ContactPhoto/RemoteContactUpdateService/UpdateProfile"
Content-Length: 1761
Host: coreservices-uat.legendonlineservices.co.uk
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

I can't think the Java version or difference between Apache-Httpclient or Jasws implementation would make any difference

could it be the Content-Type? I mean in SOAP UI the content-type is 
different to the Java client

could it be the following definition in the wsdl causing the problem?

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_RemoteContactUpdateService_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Note: I was send the same XML message to the server using the same Java code couple of days ago, and it always works.... this is a recent error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case, the webservice provider changed the endpoint from https to http
also the https connector on the server side is disabled

send MTOM over http aparently caused problem in my case

the fix is to disable the MTOM from my JAXWS client side

```
Binding binding = bp.getBinding();
SOAPBinding sb = (SOAPBinding)binding;
sb.setMTOMEnabled(false);
```

after this, the client request's content-type changed from

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;start="<rootpart*dbea05e3-9997-4835-965c-02b1ed77e6b6@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:dbea05e3-9997-4835-965c-02b1ed77e6b6";start-info="text/xml"
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
```

to

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

then I send it over http, problem solved.